# Undefined method error when trying to run around hooks

Tags: ruby, cucumber, hook, watir, page-object-gem

I am trying to run given scenarios as many times per each account type. I found out in [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236533/calling-block-multiple-times-in-cucumber-around-hook-ruby) that "around hooks" could be the best option to do it the DRY way.

Below is my code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'page-object/page_factory'
require 'page_navigation'
require 'data_magic'
require_relative 'pages/login_page'

Before do
  beforeCodeBlock
  ...
end

Around('@hooks_test') do|scenario, block|
  DataMagic.load('default.yml')     
  account_type = {"listener" => DataMagic.yml["listener_data"],
              "free" => DataMagic.yml["free_data"],
              "premium" => DataMagic.yml["premium_data"]}

  account_type .each {|key, value|
  puts "Running scenario: #{scenario.name} as #{key} user"

  visit_page(LoginPage)
  on_page(LoginPage).sign_in(value["username"],value["password"])  #Login as
  block.call

  }
end

After do
  afterCodeBlock
  ...
end
```

So when I run the feature file I get the following output and subsequent error:

```
Running scenario: Hooks test as listener user
   undefined method `visit_page' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
   /myProject/features/support/hooks.rb:38:in `block (2 levels) in   <top (required)>'
   /myProject/features/support/hooks.rb:35:in `each'
   /myProject/features/support/hooks.rb:35:in `Around'
```

Everything seems to be working as expected until the execution deals with the `visit_page` method that belongs to PageObject gem.

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly two problems I see here.

First of all you are getting the error because you did not register the `PageObject::PageFactory` module with `World`.  Add this line after the requires:

```
World(PageObject::PageFactory)
```

Second, you are using an `Around` block and calling the same Scenario multiple times.  From what I am seeing, you are doing this so that it will exercise the same behavior with different logged in users.  If the behavior is exactly the same, what are you accomplishing by running it three times?

Comment: @Cheezy- Inserting the World call didn't solve the issue. I haven't include it before because I thought the env.rb file was executed before anything and I have included the World line in there. Regarding your question, the product needs validation of same steps on different users/profiles because we have found issues related to running same steps under different profiles.